# .NET HttpWebResponse not providing Location header

Tags: header, httpwebrequest, http-headers, httpwebresponse

I have a problem obtaining Location header from the WebResponse:

```
private CookieContainer _cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
...
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);

webRequest.Method = "POST";          
webRequest.Referer = "www.xxxxx.sk";            
webRequest.Proxy = GetSystemProxy();
webRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
webRequest.CookieContainer = _cookieContainer;
webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";                                
webRequest.KeepAlive = false;            
//webRequest.Expect = "Location";
```

When i use Tamper data plugin in Firefox - I get what I want:

**Location=http://www.xxxxx.sk?i9=3522a42d0207**

But looking at `HttpWebResponse.Headers` does not contain this header (although 90 % of received headers are the same as in case of firefox)

I've tried to set .`Expect` to force the server to provide me that header, but I got error 417 Expectation failed.

The reason why I want that header is, that there is a session id in it, which I do need for further requests (Website has double security - cookies + session ID's in URL)

What I do not understand is that by default `HttpWebRequest` **will follow redirects**, so if a server sends 301/302 status code a new request will be issued to fetch the resource using the Location header. So once this final resource is fetched there will no longer be a Location header in the response. But If I set `AllowAutoRedirect` to **false**, why doesn't the header appear?

EDITED: Headers:

```
Mozilla request headers:


Host=prihlasenie.azet.sk
User-Agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13
Accept=text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language=en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding=gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset=ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive=115
Connection=keep-alive
Referer=http://www.azet.sk/
Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length=64
POSTDATA=form%5Busername%5D=yyyyyyyyyy&form%5Bpassword%5D=zzzzzzzzzz
--
Mozilla response headers:



Status=Found - 302
Date=Fri, 14 Jan 2011 13:12:37 GMT
Server=Apache
Pragma=no-cache
Expires=Fri, 14 Jan 2011 13:12:37 +0000
Cache-Control=post-check=0, pre-check=0, no-cache, must-revalidate
Set-Cookie=AZetSecId=3a2f118910; expires=Fri, 28-Jan-2011 13:12:37 GMT; path=/; domain=.azet.sk
Location=http://www.azet.sk/?i9=6ffcf488a877
Vary=User-Agent,Accept-Encoding
X-Served-By=prihlasenieweb-04
Content-Encoding=gzip
Content-Length=1124
Keep-Alive=timeout=15, max=82
Connection=Keep-Alive
Content-Type=text/html

--
------------------------------------------------
---
HttpWebRequest headers:

{Referer: http://www.xxxx.sk
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: prihlasenie.xxxx.sk
Content-Length: 59
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Close
}

and I'm doing:

byte[] paramBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postParameters);
webRequest.ContentLength = paramBytes.Length;

using (Stream requestStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
{
    requestStream.Write(paramBytes, 0, paramBytes.Length);
}
---
HttpWebResponse headers:

{Pragma: no-cache
Vary: User-Agent,Accept-Encoding
X-Served-By: prihlasenieweb-05
Connection: close
Content-Length: 2113
Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0, no-cache, must-revalidate
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Thu, 13 Jan 2011 20:56:21 GMT
Expires: Thu, 13 Jan 2011 20:56:21 +0000
Set-Cookie: xxxxSecId=b425262c2e; expires=Thu, 27-Jan-2011 20:56:21 GMT; path=/; domain=.xxxx.sk
Server: Apache
}
```

Comment: Why do you use "Expect" header at all? The other option would be that the cookieContainer is not initialized properly prior to the request.

Comment: Hmm. sounds like a bug. can you get a system.net trace log and put it on pastebin? Here are the instructions http://ferozedaud.blogspot.com/2009/08/tracing-with-systemnet.html

Comment: I did not mean to use Expect normally, but it was worth a try..

Comment: Why do you think it's a bug? anyways I could sniff out the packet coming out from my machine and compare the http headers to the firefox ones..

Comment: @PaN1C_Showt1Me well, the point is: do you need any form of authentication? If so the issue would be the session (since it's left empty). And what does the server return when "Expect" is not present. (The header has totally different purpose and 417 is a good result with it). Post the headers of 301/302 that you get w/ HttpWebRequest

Comment: Side note: POST requests should not be redirected in general and usually it's 302/303 to be followed by GET (not 301)

Comment: The cookie part is missing in the HttpWebRequest, you do have a cookie in the 1st post. In your question you explain the website requires that cookie. It's a possible reason. (note: you have posted plenty of data to identify the xxxx domain, may want to mangle it).

Comment: Also: could you print the status code from the HttpWebRequest. (or status line)

Comment: Well I'm not intending to hide the domain, although I find it better not to show it directly.. but you definitely know what it's name.

Comment: To the point - initial login with cookies. I think that cookie is persisted from the last session.. let me try it with the cache cleared.

Comment: StatusCode is OK from the HttpWebResponse..

Comment: @PaN1C_Showt1Me: Well, you dont get redirect at all then :) printing the content after OK status will give you extra insight why it happens [See the point of the cookies again]. I guess you use a web form to logon w/ FireFox in that same the cookie might be set during the page containing the form (i.e. the simple GET)

Comment: WEll you were right.. I got it working ! after the logon the server sent OK with the content: "Logging in".

Comment: so: cookieContainer is not initialized properly prior to the request is the right answer then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lays within the initialization of the cookies since the webserver may rely on them to start the authentication process.

Extra note: please add (http) cookie in the tags ("http-headers" one covers it but it's too a global tag)